# textbox is stretching and moving upside once we click on button

Tags: css, magento

please visit [link](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/wtest4.html)

this is e commerce site where we can buy products.

please click on "Add to cart" button , than you can see :

[image]

this is cloth product, we have to select **"color" and "charactar"** first than we have to click on "add to cart" .
if we select "color" and "charactar" first, than there will be no problem. but if we click directly on **Add to cart** than only problem, textbox next to "color" will stretch and move little upside.

What i want is if we click on "Add to cart"  directly than also it should display as like before only [css part ]

Comment: can you please what css is written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to do the following changes to the styles.css

line no: 282

```
.validation-advice { clear:both; min-height:13px; margin:5px 0; padding-left:13px; padding-top:2px; line-height:13px; background:url(../images/validation_advice_bg.png) 0px 3px no-repeat; color:#e70808; float:left; width:70%; text-align:left}
```

line no: 1953 where the comments are /*vikas*/

```
  #product-options-wrapper dl dt {
       display: inline-block;
      margin-top: 13px;
  }

 #product-options-wrapper dl dd {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
  }

 #product-options-wrapper dl dd { width: 35%; }
```

line no: 1036

```
.product-options dd select { /*width:100%;*/ margin-bottom:5px; height:auto}
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Happy Coding...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  .validation-advice{   /**add few property in this class**/
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        bottom: -11px;
    }  

    #product-options-wrapper dl dd{  /**add relative here **/
    position:relative;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try implementing the following changes:

https://gyazo.com/c30af863033c32797f3f1435a37adef8 position:relative - for the parent container. 
https://gyazo.com/1b5fd06e48cb8b0530f898ae8b968a35 - position:absolute; top:30px; left:0px; width:auto; - for the message block.

But be careful! If you use this solution, you should always keep the space below the main block a little bigger than the height of the message.

Also, please add top:0; for the following block: 
https://gyazo.com/01519f7a4e4d7325d3946e4c70c00122

It should be 'stuck' to the upper part of the window without space: 
https://gyazo.com/13010dd395ca5bb18367daa670943fc6